# Tranformar Multiplos arrays em apenas um array

Tags: php, array

Em determinado processo do meu sistema, eu recebo como retorno de uma função um `array` de `characteristics` e esse `array` pode conter diversas informações, inclusive outros `arrays` com nomes diferente para cada tipo de informação. Ex:

```
Apartamento:
Characteristics => [
 ["external_area"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=> "varanda"
      [1]=> "lavanderia"
      [2]=> "piscina"
      [3]=> "muros"
      [4]=> "area_serviço"
    }
    ["bedroom"]=>
     array(12) {
      [0]=> "piso_frio"
      [1]=> "alvenaria"
      [2]=> "azulejo_teto"
      [3]=> "massa_corrida"
      }
   ]

Casa:
Characteristics => [
 ["internal_area"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=> "mesa de madeira"
      [1]=> "area"
    }
    ["options"]=>
     array(12) {
      [0]=> "2 andares"
      [1]=> "banheiro externo"
      }
   ]
```

e eu preciso que tudo fique dentro de um array só, por exemplo de apartamento, ficaria:

```
Characeristics => [
   [0]=> "varanda"
   [1]=> "lavanderia"
   [2]=> "piscina"
   [3]=> "muros"
   [4]=> "area_serviço"
   [5]=> "piso_frio"
   [6]=> "alvenaria"
   [7]=> "azulejo_teto"
   [8]=> "massa_corrida"
]
```

EDIT: Lembrando que eu não sei os nomes dos `arrays` que vem dentro de `Characteristics`

Comment: Pode haver repetições?

Comment: Não. Tanto arrays quanto os elementos do array não se repetem no mesmo tipo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma vez precisei disso e usei [esta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320156/1001109).

```
function flatten($array) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
    return $return;
}
```

Essa forma funciona independente do número de sub-arrays que você tenha e também independente das chaves. Ex.: https://eval.in/671144

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar a função [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($item, $key) 
{
    global $Characeristics;
    if (! is_array( $item ) ) $Characeristics[] = $item;
});

$result = array( "Characeristics" => $Characeristics );
```

Ou seja, se o valor em que está a passar no momento não for um array (será a tua string de característica) é adicionado a um novo array.

[A funcionar o ideone](http://ideone.com/TfKH7Z)

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo de como pode fazer:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(1, 2, 3),
    1 => array(4, 5, 6)
);

$rs = array();
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $rs = array_merge($rs, array_values($v));
}
unset($arr);

print_r($rs);
```

Esteja ciente de que isso é um exemplo. O array original da pergunta possui um nível a mais, porém, pode resolver com a mesma lógica.

Para o seu caso deve ficar algo assim:

```
$rs = array('Characteristics' => array()); // Esse array serve para guardar o resultado final

foreach ($arr['Characteristics']['external_area'] as $v) {
    //aqui mescla os valores
    $rs['Characteristics'] = array_merge($rs, array_values($v));
}
unset($arr); // Se não precisar mais desses dados, apague-os

print_r($rs);
```

## Nomes das chaves

Caso o nome da primeira chave seja desconhecida, pode obtê-la com a função key()

```
$arr['a']['b'] = array();
echo key($arr['a']);
// retorna 'b'
```

Para o seu caso específico:

```
$arr['Characteristics']['external_area'] = array();
echo key($arr['Characteristics']);
// retorna 'external_area'
```

Implementando no código de exemplo

```
$rs = array('Characteristics' => array()); // Esse array serve para guardar o resultado final

$k = key($arr['Characteristics']); // obtém o nome da primeira chave

foreach ($arr['Characteristics'][$k] as $v) {
    //aqui mescla os valores
    $rs['Characteristics'] = array_merge($rs, array_values($v));
}
unset($arr); // Se não precisar mais desses dados, apague-os

print_r($rs);
```

Comment: Eu não tenho como saber o nome do array do segundo nivel. 'external_area' pode ter qualquer nome ou pode não existir.

Comment: adicionei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Desenvolvi uma função que percorre o array e vai mesclando os array, dê uma olhada, considerei o array `$characteristics` como o primeiro que você postou na pergunta, espero que ajude

```
var_dump(getAllCharacteristics($characteristics));
die;

function getAllCharacteristics($characteristics) {
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($characteristics as $characteristic) {
        if (is_array($characteristic)) {
            $newArray = array_merge($newArray, getAllCharacteristics($characteristic));
        } else {
            $newArray[] = $characteristic;
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

A saída da função *var_dump* seria:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "varanda"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "lavanderia"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "piscina"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "muros"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "area_serviço"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "piso_frio"
  [6]=>
  string(9) "alvenaria"
  [7]=>
  string(12) "azulejo_teto"
  [8]=>
  string(13) "massa_corrida"
}
```